# Tensorflow won't import with sudo python3

Tags: cuda, tensorflow

I'm working with a remote Ubuntu 18.04 instance where to write files with python I must run `sudo python`. One of my python scripts imports tensorflow which when running with `sudo` prefix I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had this issue before when I had cuda 10.1 installed so I reverted back to cuda 10.0 and tensorflow imports fine when running python script WITHOUT `sudo` command but the error persists if `sudo` is used.

Does anyone know what could be the problem.

PS I have cuda path added to the environment variables like so:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Comment: maybe I'm completely out of my depth here but is it possible tensorflow resets the working dir? in which case it could potentially be working off of root or root's home, you could resolve this by placing symbolic links to the needed files there.

Answer (score 0):

When running things with sudo, your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH get reset to a (safer) default, so your CUDA libraries are no longer found.  You could reset them explicitly in your script.